# WPF MVVM Composite Application in Office (Excel 2007) Add-in

Tags: wpf, mvvm, vsto, prism

I'm using WPF MVVM to create a wizard in Excel 2007. The wizard code is based on [this internationalized wizard](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF).

Because WPF must be contained within an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) all of my views are user controls, there is no App.xaml. Instead I create my WPF Application when the host WinForm is instantiated and bind my application resources dynamically as described [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/).

```
Private _wpfApplication As Windows.Application
Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    '   WPF application instance
    _wpfApplication = Application.Current()
    If Application.Current Is Nothing Then
        _wpfApplication = New Application()
    End If
    '   Merge in your application resources.
    _wpfApplication.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(TryCast(Application.LoadComponent(New Uri("Pitchbook.Excel.ChartWizard;Component/Themes/Generic.xaml", UriKind.Relative)), ResourceDictionary))
End Sub
Private Sub ChartWizard_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    '   Create the WPF UserControl.
    Dim uc As New MainWindow()
    '   Assign the WPF UserControl to the ElementHost control's child property.
    ehMaster.Child = uc
End Sub
```

This works fine for the one module I have created so far. I have many modules to create and rather than having a WinForm container for each module I would really like to take the application to the next level by creating a composite application using Prism. I want to somehow have a generic WinForm that plays a similar role to App.xaml. When the user clicks a button on my ribbon I could launch this generic host WinForm bind the Shell.xaml to the ElementHost and use the bootstrapper to load the relevant modules based on some parameter or configuration that maps a ribbon button to a set of modules that should be loaded into the generic host container.

I'm struggling with the logic to do this and I wanted to get some opinions regarding the feasibility of this approach and if it is possible best ways it might be done. Basically I need to add the two layers in red to the existing composite application architecture.

http://www.patternjuggler.org/downloads/officecompositeapp.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Igor Moochnick goes a long way to answering this question with the following article.

[Office Applications via Prism of Unity](http://igorshare.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/office-applications-via-prism-of-unity/trackback/)

Answer (score 2):

[VSTOContrib](https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/VSTOContrib) is an excellent Open Source framework for building decoupled applications in Office with WPF and MVVM. As well as support for WPF, there is Denpendency Injection, management for Task Panes / Ribbons / Event handling in both document / spreadsheet and application contexts, strategies for ensuring COM Interop memory allocation is managed properly, assistance for one-click installation... etc.

Essentially, all the traditional pain-points of Office Add-in development have been addressed. I have found it has transformed my approach to Office Add-in work.